# incrementing a field in a table when insertion in another table occurs

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have two tables as shown:

```
user
id    plan     course_limit     username 
10                  0            ahmad
```

note: plan is enum field containing `'','a','b','c'`.

```
course
id    user_id   username
1       10        ahmad
```

Now I want when a user insert into course as shown I want the `course_limit` to increment by 1 for that user so that I can apply a limit.

Comment: This is a situation for an INSERT Trigger - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Not related to the problem, but... Let me get this right. When you insert a course, you want to increase the limit? Heh, not much of a limit now is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger with the following code.

```
CREATE 
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER databasename.AI_course_each
AFTER INSERT
ON databasename.course
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

  UPDATE user SET user.course_limit = user.course_limit + 1
  WHERE user.user_id = new.user_id; 

END;
```

**Some explanation**
You create a trigger that fires **once** for every row `FOR EACH ROW` that is inserted `AFTER INSERT` into table course.

When you insert into the table you can trigger `BEFORE` and `AFTER` the insert is done.
If you want to be able to prevent the insert you fire before, if you just want to do useful work, you fire after.
The inserted fields can be accessed via a *dummy* table 'new'.

So here after each insert the UPDATE statement gets executed.

**More trigger options**
You can also use triggers `BEFORE UPDATE`, `AFTER UPDATE`,`BEFORE DELETE` and  `AFTER DELETE`.

In the update and delete cases you get an extra dummy table `old` that you can use to refer to the data in the table before the update or delete happened.

Lots more is possible, but I'll keep it simple for now.

See http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers for more info.

Comment: That's what this site is about :-) If you like the answer you can accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: what if i select a plan and i want to apply restriction on user that he cannot enter more than 10 courses.

Comment: Better make that a new question, the answer does not fit in this space. Hint: it requires a before insert trigger, or a select on the number of courses before you do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [**trigger**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) should solve your problem : with that, you'll be able to register SQL code, on your MySQL server, that runs when certain events occur *(like insertion)*.

Comment: like how i don,t know anything about triggers thanks for ur help.

Comment: how can i use triggers with php.

Comment: Triggers are not related to PHP : they are purely a MySQL feature.

Comment: It's not something you do with PHP. You send some SQL to the DB server once, with instructions what it should do when an insert occurs. See the MySQL docs for detailed instructions.